# Index creation memory using SSMS 2008r2

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I change Index creation memory Using SSMS 2008R2?

What is the best practice for Index creation memory?

Comment: "The index create memory option is self-configuring and usually works without requiring adjustment."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is not to change the "index create memory (KB)" setting from its default value of 0, because by default, SQL Server 2008 dynamically manages the amount of memory allocated for index creation operations.

If additional memory is needed for creating indexes, and the memory is available based on the server memory configuration settings, the server will allocate additional memory for index creation operations. If additional memory is needed but not available, index creation will use the memory already allocated to perform index creation. However, if you do experience difficulties creating indexes, like in case there is a high degree of parallelism (lots of simultaneous index creation operations), you might consider increasing the value of this option.

To use a specific index creation memory allocation, complete the following steps:

1. Open SSMS. In the Server Properties dialog box, go to the Memory page and set a value in the Index Creation Memory box. Note that this value is set in kilobytes.
2. Click OK to save the changes

Note that the amount of memory allocated to index creation operations should be at least as large as the minimum memory per query. If it is not, SQL Server will use the amount of memory specified as the minimum memory per query and display a warning about this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change it [as per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175123%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) using s`p_configure`
2. There is no best practice: I've never known anyone (including myself) to change this, ever.

Comment: "I've never known anyone to change this, " - Ditto.